# C#, WinForms and application icon

Tags: c#, winforms, ico

This is an unimportant question. I been trying to tidy up my application, and keep my root folder as clean as possible. One file I have never been able to move out, is the application ico file. If I move it to say, Resources folder, which seems the logical place, and select it in

Project | properties | Application | Icon and manifest | Icon:

Then it is copied back to root folder again :-) Anyone found a way put the icon file outside of the root folder?

Comment: Its possible.  First copy the icon yourself with Explorer.  Then type the relative path name in the setting without using the dialog to select it (so, say, "resources\youricon.ico").  Then delete the original.

Answer (score 1):

If you have placed your application icon in the e.g. Resources folder, you can add it to the project by the project context menu item 'Add > Existing Item...'. Then select it in the dialog, click the small down arrow on the right side if the "Add" button and click "Add As Link". If you open the project properties, you can select the icon now and it is not copied to the projects root folder.

So, for bigger solutions, you may create one folder with icons, images etc. that can by shared in the entire solution without any copy operation.

That also works for source code files, then you should declare classes as `internal` to prevent problems. I use that sometimes for small helper classes or extensions to prevent to reference an e.g. (bigger) common assembly.